# $R$ be a ring with unity such that its subrings (not necessarily with unity) satisfies ascending and descending chain condition ; then is $R$ finite?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity such that its subrings (not necessarily with unity) satisfies ascending and descending chain condition ; then is $R$ finite ?

NOTE : [If $R$ is an integral domain with unity having only finitely many subdomains (not necessarily with unity), then is $R$ finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840253/if-r-is-an-integral-domain-with-unity-having-only-finitely-many-subdomains-no) gives a positive answer for a very very special case

Comment: Is $R$ a subring of itself?

Comment: @DHMO : of-course ... but why does that matter ?